# Error trying to install a new document class on Mac

Tags: mactex, texpad

I'm using LaTeX to write a thesis for my University, and have to use a special premade document class (`rtthesis`). However, I can't find a way to install this document class. I've tried typesetting with both TexShop and Texpad (my usual choice of TeX editor), and both complain that the `rtthesis.cls` file can't be found.

I have moved all files relating to the class to `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/rtthesis/` and ran both `mktexlsr` and `texhash`, but neither helped. When typesetting, only this error is returned:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `rrthesis.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)
```

Could someone provide me with information on what I've done wrong, or what else I can do to install a new document class on Mac?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You seem to have a typo in the `\documentclass` directive: The error message states that TeX can't find the file named `rrthesis.cls` -- which is as it should be because -- inferring from your write-up -- the file in question is named `rtthesis.cls`.

Comment: There is no need of running `mktexlsr` (which is just the same script as `texhash`) when you add something in the "personal tree" (that is, under `~/Library/texmf`). As Mico said, check the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the `rtthesis.cly`in the folder that contains your file `tex`?

It's what I do for the theme of my university... You'll just have to do that with every doc that you write with this theme...